# Pigeonhole principle: Show that out of 7 lines in a plane we can choose 3 paralel lines or 4 concurrent lines.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

There are $7$ lines in a plane. Show that we can  always pick either $3$ paralel lines or $4$ concurrent lines. Show that it won't work for $6$ lines.

I have no idea where to start with this.

Comment: I don't entirely understand your question: (a) do you mean rays and not lines, specifically? (b) Why are lines that form the edges of a regular 7-gon not a counter-example to the first scenario? Any two lines will not be parallel, and any set of three lines will not be concurrent (have a common intersection point).

Comment: If you arrange the rays as a regular septagon, doesn’t that provide a counterexample?

Comment: @DominikS,  they are supposed to be lines. Sorry, fixed it.

Comment: @RobertShore, first I'd like to show using pigeonhole principle that you can either choose 3 paralel lines or 4 concurrent lines out of the 7 lines. How do I do that?

Comment: I agree with RobertShore that the septagon would be a counter-example. @runtotherescue: Is it? If not, why not? Or did we misunderstand your problem description?

Comment: @DominikS, but isn't septagon an example of choosing more than 4 concurrent lines?   Then it's not an counter example, is it?

Comment: There are 7 lines. We have to prove using pigeonhole principle that we can choose either 3 parallel or 4 concurrent lines. (That's the first question) and the second question is to show that it won't work for 6 lines.

Comment: Are we talking about the same definition of [concurrent lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_lines)? In the sense that they intersect at a single, common point?

Comment: I think they actually meant four lines that are pairwise intersecting.

Comment: Use as the pigeonholes the slope of the lines, and show that you either have 4 or more pigeonholes or else that a pigionhole has 3 or more pigeons/lines.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you meant to prove that there are either $3$ parallel lines or $4$ lines pairwise intersecting. Let’s divide all the $7$ lines into groups of parallel lines. Let there be not $3$ parallel lines. Then each group contains at most $2$ lines. So since there are $7$ lines in total there are at least $4$ groups (by pigeonhole principle). Now take a line from each of $4$ groups and you get $4$ lines pairwise intersecting